# cloth with ammo softBodyHelpers.CreatePatch

Tags: three.js, physics

I'm trying to use the three.js physics cloth demo to create a tablecloth but the resulting cloth is always a vertical banner. Is uses the ammo softBodyHelpers.CreatePatch function to make the softbody but I could not find doc on how this can be used. Does any one know how this can be adapted to make a table cloth ? My initial mesh looks fine as a table cloth but as soon as the first  physics loop updates the mesh it moves immediately vertices into a vertical banner.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ammo.js github page](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/):

> ammo.js is a direct port of the Bullet physics engine to JavaScript,
>   using Emscripten. The source code is translated directly to
>   JavaScript, without human rewriting, so functionality should be
>   identical to the original Bullet.

Looking at [the documentation for Bullet's `SoftBodyHelpers`](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/structbtSoftBodyHelpers.html), `CreatePatch` is indeed meant for rectangular geometry only.

Good news, though - there's a separate function called `CreateEllipsoid`.

Comment: OK thanks for the tip ; I will look at this other function and will give feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any other static geometry in the scene for the cloth to collide with? Otherwise it will just be a sheet, falling through frictionless space.

Comment: Yes, there is a rigid body floor and the cloth just smashes nicely down on that floor but just as a falling curtain and not an horizontal table cloth

Comment: Yes, but I also tested another solution, using a softbody (bullet function : softBodyHelpers.CreateFromTriMesh) associated to a plane geometry (pressure zero) which also works. I think this can be closed.